# Jquery + change label value without ID

Tags: jquery, label

I have this label:

```
<div id="edit-my-radios-0-wrapper" class="form-item">
<label class="option" for="edit-my-radios-0">
<input id="edit-my-radios-0" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="0">
£25
</label>
```

Which I want to change the value of using JQuery.  Unfortunately I have no control over how it is created, and with an id, I'm not sure if it's even possible to target it.

Does anyone have nay idea how to target it?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean by value of the label? Do you want to change the <input /> as well as the text?

Comment: The point of the `for` attribute is so you don't have to wrap the `input` with `label`.
So you can either use `for` in the `label` and make sure it targets a unique id or wrap `label` around the `input` and not use `for` at all..

Answer (score 11):

I realize this question is about a year old, but I thought I'd answer it anyway...

To select/target a label that doesn't have an id, you can use the value in `for=` as follows:

```
$('label[for=edit-my-radios-0]').html('New Label Here');
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by value you mean the HTML inside of the label. You can select the label by the class name.

```
$('.option').html('[Your HTML here']);
```

Take a look at the [jQuery selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: In that case, we just need to tweak the selector a bit. Will the label always be inside a div with this id: "edit-my-radios-0-wrapper"? Basically, we need to determine the selectors that are needed to return that lable. Think of it like building a WHERE statement in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div.form-item lable.option").html("ValueToChange");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#edit-my-radios-0-wrapper label')` will get this as the wrapper has an `id`. Targetting it by `class` anywhere may cause trouble with other elements on the page with the same class.

-- edit --

Just seen that the `div` doesn't close after the label. Looks like you can't target a specific label but can target all with `$('.option')`

-- edit --

I'm determined to make this a decent answer rather than what I've served up so far!

Using `$('label:has(#edit-my-radios-0)')` will target that label

Answer (score 0):

it's simple please try this code

```
$('label[for="edit-my-radios-0"]').html('<input id="edit-my-radios-0" class="form-radio" type="radio" value="0">£180');
```